# Rails: Filter index results with nested resource in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, controllers

I have 2 models: brand and coupon, coupon is nested within brand. On the index page for coupon, I want to show all coupons with the current brand id.

Example on /brand/1/coupons - want to show all the coupons with brand id = 1

Code is below

```
create_table "brands", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "logo"
end

create_table "coupons", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "brand_id",   limit: 255
  t.string   "code"
  t.date     "expiry"
  t.string   "link"
  t.string   "details"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :coupons
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :coupons
end

class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :brand
end

class CouponsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_coupon, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @coupons = Coupon.find(params[:brand_id]
end

end
```

Error I get when going to brands/1/coupons ...

```
NoMethodError in CouponsController#index
undefined method `each' for #<Coupon:0x000001068e8f58>


  else
    match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
    match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
  end
end
```

Comment: The `find` method finds a record by ID — this method does not return a collection, which is why `each` is undefined. If you want to return a collection of coupons for a brand, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your routes are setup correctly, this should work:

```
@coupons = Coupon.where(brand_id: params[:brand_id])
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :brands do
  resources :coupons
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
@coupons = Coupon.all
or
@coupons = Coupon.where(brand_id: params[:id])
```

in view

```
@coupons.each do |coupon|
  coupon.brand_id
  or 
  coupon.brand.id  # but in this case your will have N+1 problem
```